# How to fetch the first row a user has save on a table in php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My webpage basically saves and fetches information about the employment history of an employee; Each employee having at least 10 to 15 work experience with the company; My issue is that i am having trouble fetching the data for date hired.

Here are the details of table wexp

LNAME|FNAME|WFROM|WTO|PT|DEPT|MS|SGSI|SOA|GOVS

I was wondering if it is possible to fetch the last row for a specific employee something like in mysql_fetch_assoc

```
 $wexp = "SELECT * FROM wexp WHERE LNAME='$lname' && FNAME='$fname';
 $viewwexp = mysql_query($wexp,$con);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($viewwexp))
```

Any assistance is much appreciated; I am also open for suggestion if you think what i have in mind is not possible

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't all-caps your title. It's annoying and is what has earned you the 3 downvotes so far.

Comment: sorry about that didn't mean to annoy anybody

Comment: Isn't this viable for sql injection attacks? And there is a deprecation warning for mysQL_ functions for php 5.5 and up...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who have the same concern as i am; Since the table was using auto increment for ID; All i needed was to check the highest id save for that specific employee; My code is shown below

```
SELECT * FROM wexp WHERE LNAME='$lname'&& FNAME='$fname' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$wexp = "SELECT * FROM wexp WHERE LNAME = '".$lname."' and FNAME = '".$fname."' ";
$viewwexp = mysql_query($wexp,$con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($viewwexp)){
  $fname = $row['FNAME'];
  //onwards
}
```

Comment: Isn't this viable for sql injection attacks? And there is a deprecation warning for mysQL_ functions for php 5.5 and up...